# Pixel Array to UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, cgimage

I've been trying to figure out how to convert an array of rgb pixel data to a UIImage in Swift.

I'm keeping the rgb data per pixel in a simple struct:

```
public struct PixelData {
   var a: Int
   var r: Int
   var g: Int
   var b: Int
}
```

I've made my way to the following function, but the resulting image is incorrect:

```
func imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels:[PixelData], width: Int, height: Int)-> UIImage {
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo:CGBitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let bitsPerComponent:Int = 8
    let bitsPerPixel:Int = 32

    assert(pixels.count == Int(width * height))

    var data = pixels // Copy to mutable []
    let providerRef = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(
        NSData(bytes: &data, length: data.count * sizeof(PixelData))
    )

    let cgim = CGImageCreate(
        width,
        height,
        bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel,
        width * Int(sizeof(PixelData)),
        rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo,
        providerRef,
        nil,
        true,
        kCGRenderingIntentDefault
    )
    return UIImage(CGImage: cgim)!
}
```

Any tips or pointers on how to properly convert an rgb array to an UIImage?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Note:** This is a solution for iOS creating a `UIImage`.  For a solution for macOS and `NSImage`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62363476/1630618).

Your only problem is that the data types in your `PixelData` structure need to be `UInt8`.  I created a test image in a Playground with the following:

```
public struct PixelData {
    var a: UInt8
    var r: UInt8
    var g: UInt8
    var b: UInt8
}

var pixels = [PixelData]()

let red = PixelData(a: 255, r: 255, g: 0, b: 0)
let green = PixelData(a: 255, r: 0, g: 255, b: 0)
let blue = PixelData(a: 255, r: 0, g: 0, b: 255)

for _ in 1...300 {
    pixels.append(red)
}
for _ in 1...300 {
    pixels.append(green)
}
for _ in 1...300 {
    pixels.append(blue)
}

let image = imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels: pixels, width: 30, height: 30)
```

---

**Update for Swift 4:**

I updated `imageFromARGB32Bitmap` to work with Swift 4.  The function now returns a `UIImage?` and `guard` is used to return `nil` if anything goes wrong.

```
func imageFromARGB32Bitmap(pixels: [PixelData], width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage? {
    guard width > 0 && height > 0 else { return nil }
    guard pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }

    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitsPerPixel = 32

    var data = pixels // Copy to mutable []
    guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: NSData(bytes: &data,
                            length: data.count * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size)
        )
        else { return nil }

    guard let cgim = CGImage(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow: width * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size,
        space: rgbColorSpace,
        bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
        provider: providerRef,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: .defaultIntent
        )
        else { return nil }

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgim)
}
```

---

**Making it a convenience initializer for UIImage:**

This function works well as a `convenience` initializer for `UIImage`.  Here is the implementation:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(pixels: [PixelData], width: Int, height: Int) {
        guard width > 0 && height > 0, pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }
        var data = pixels
        guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: Data(bytes: &data, count: data.count * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size) as CFData)
            else { return nil }
        guard let cgim = CGImage(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 32,
            bytesPerRow: width * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue),
            provider: providerRef,
            decode: nil,
            shouldInterpolate: true,
            intent: .defaultIntent)
        else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgim)
    }
}
```

Here is an example of its usage:

```
// Generate a 500x500 image of randomly colored pixels

let height = 500
let width = 500

var pixels: [PixelData] = .init(repeating: .init(a: 0, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0), count: width * height)
for index in pixels.indices {
    pixels[index].a = 255
    pixels[index].r = .random(in: 0...255)
    pixels[index].g = .random(in: 0...255)
    pixels[index].b = .random(in: 0...255)
}
let image = UIImage(pixels: pixels, width: width, height: height)
```

Comment: I copy pasted this code and the result was blurred when I used `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` to save the photo. It seems like the image is being resized which is causing the blur. Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: @rayaantaneja I think that is because the photo is saved in JPEG format.  I'm not sure how to get it to use PNG instead.  You might need to use another method call.

Comment: I got it to work by using `.pngData()` and using that to create another image. The image still looks blurry but that's only because the iPhone photo library scales stuff up. If you view it using anything else, such as Preview on Mac, it looks perfect.

Answer (score 9):

## Update for Swift 3

```
struct PixelData {
    var a: UInt8 = 0
    var r: UInt8 = 0
    var g: UInt8 = 0
    var b: UInt8 = 0
}

func imageFromBitmap(pixels: [PixelData], width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage? {
    assert(width > 0)

    assert(height > 0)

    let pixelDataSize = MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size
    assert(pixelDataSize == 4)

    assert(pixels.count == Int(width * height))

    let data: Data = pixels.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
        return Data(buffer: $0)
    }

    let cfdata = NSData(data: data) as CFData
    let provider: CGDataProvider! = CGDataProvider(data: cfdata)
    if provider == nil {
        print("CGDataProvider is not supposed to be nil")
        return nil
    }
    let cgimage: CGImage! = CGImage(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 32,
        bytesPerRow: width * pixelDataSize,
        space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue),
        provider: provider,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true,
        intent: .defaultIntent
    )
    if cgimage == nil {
        print("CGImage is not supposed to be nil")
        return nil
    }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgimage)
}
```

Comment: This is really good but it's a bit long-winded.  I would suggest changing the assertions to simple `guard` statements, and using `guard let` instead of `if`ing for nils. 

In my implementation I also used `UInt` to prevent negative width and heights.