# Converting TrueDepth data to grayscale image produces distorted image

Tags: ios, avfoundation, cvpixelbuffer, truedepth-camera

I'm getting the depth data from the TrueDepth camera, and converting it to a [grayscale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677133/how-to-reconstruct-grayscale-image-from-intensity-values). (I realize I could pass the `AVDepthData` to a `CIImage` constructor, however, for testing purposes, I want to make sure my array is populated correctly, therefore manually constructing an image would ensure that is the case.)

I notice that when I try to convert the grayscale image, I get weird results. Namely, the image appears in the top half, and the bottom half is distorted (sometimes showing the image twice, other times showing nonsense).

For example:

> Expected output (i.e. `CIImage(depthData: depthData)`):
>
> [image]

> Actual output (20% of the time):
>
> [image]

> Actual output (80% of the time):
>
> [image]

I started with [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera) and tried to [extract the pixel in the CVPixelBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569750/get-pixel-value-from-cvpixelbufferref-in-swift).

```
let depthDataMap: CVPixelBuffer = ...
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthDataMap) // 640
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthDataMap) // 480
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(depthDataMap) // 1280
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthDataMap)
assert(kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16 == CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(depthDataMap))
let byteBuffer = unsafeBitCast(baseAddress, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float16>.self)

var pixels = [Float]()
for row in 0..<height {
  for col in 0..<width {
    let byteBufferIndex = col + row * bytesPerRow
    let distance = byteBuffer[byteBufferIndex]
    pixels += [distance]
  }
}

// TODO: render pixels as a grayscale image
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

You should always unwrap the call to `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` so that you don't miss important warnings.

---

Turns out the problem is how the value inside the byteBuffer is being accessed. If instead of using `unsafeBitCast()` you use the method Apple uses in their example (`assumingMemoryBound`), you will get the correct results.

Although it looks like:

```
// BAD CODE

let byteBuffer = unsafeBitCast(baseAddress, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float16>.self)
// ...
let byteBufferIndex = col + row * bytesPerRow
let distance = byteBuffer[byteBufferIndex]
```

... should behave the same as:

```
// GOOD CODE

let rowData = baseAddress! + row * bytesPerRow
let distance = rowData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float16.self)[col]
```

... the two are in fact very different, with the former producing the bad results mentioned above, and the latter producing good results.

The final (fixed) code should look like this:

```
let depthDataMap: CVPixelBuffer = ...
let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(depthDataMap) // 640
let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(depthDataMap) // 480
let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(depthDataMap) // 1280
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthDataMap)!
assert(kCVPixelFormatType_DepthFloat16 == CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(depthDataMap))

var pixels = [Float]()
for row in 0..<height {
  for col in 0..<width {
    let rowData = baseAddress + row * bytesPerRow
    let distance = rowData.assumingMemoryBound(to: Float16.self)[col]
    pixels += [distance]
  }
}

// TODO: render pixels as a grayscale image
```

---

I'm actually not sure why this is the case because we know:

```
assert(MemoryLayout<Float16>.size == 2)
assert(width == 640)
assert(bytesPerRow == 1280)
assert(width * 2 == bytesPerRow)
```

This seems to imply that there are no extra bytes at the end of a row, and we should be able to read it as one giant array.

If anyone knows why the former fails, please share!

---

**Update:**

If you force unwrap the call to `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`:

```
let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(depthDataMap)!
```

... things start to make a bit more sense.

Namely, you will see a warning on this line:

```
let byteBuffer = unsafeBitCast(baseAddress, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float16>.self)
```

> ⚠️ 'unsafeBitCast' from 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer' gives a type to a raw pointer and may lead to undefined behavior

> ⚠️ Use the 'assumingMemoryBound' method if the pointer is known to point to an existing value or array of type 'Float16' in memory

I guess the results I seeing were related to the "undefined behavior" warning.

The lesson, therefore, is that you should always unwrap the result of `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress` before attempting to use it (e.g. in `unsafeBitCast`).

Comment: If you cast the base address before/without unwrapping it you're presumably casting the pointer to the optional enum instead