# Create Random Pixel Images in Swift

Tags: java, swift, image, image-processing, pixel

I want to create a random pixel generator in swift.

How would I be able to create something like the below codes in swift?

Java program to demonstrate creation of random pixel image

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
public class RandomImage 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException 
    { 
        // Image file dimensions 
        int width = 640, height = 320; 

        // Create buffered image object 
        BufferedImage img = null; 
        img = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 

        // file object 
        File f = null; 

        // create random values pixel by pixel 
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
        { 
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
            { 
                int a = (int)(Math.random()*256); //generating 
                int r = (int)(Math.random()*256); //values 
                int g = (int)(Math.random()*256); //less than 
                int b = (int)(Math.random()*256); //256 

                int p = (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b; //pixel 

                img.setRGB(x, y, p); 
            } 
        } 

        // write image 
        try
        { 
            f = new File("G:\\Out.jpg"); 
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f); 
        } 
        catch(IOException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Error: " + e); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

This is what I was only able to achieve. From the below code, you'll have know that i'm definitely a swift newbie.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

                let height=500
                let width=500
                for y in 0..<height {
                    for x in 0..<width {

                    }
                }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution for macOS (based on [this iOS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30958427/1630618)) that creates an `NSImage`:

```
public struct Pixel {
    var a,r,g,b: UInt8
}

extension NSImage {
    convenience init?(pixels: [Pixel], width: Int, height: Int) {
        guard width > 0 && height > 0, pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }
        var data = pixels
        guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: Data(bytes: &data, count: data.count * MemoryLayout<Pixel>.size) as CFData)
            else { return nil }
        guard let cgim = CGImage(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 32,
            bytesPerRow: width * MemoryLayout<Pixel>.size,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue),
            provider: providerRef,
            decode: nil,
            shouldInterpolate: true,
            intent: .defaultIntent)
        else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgim, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
    }
}
```

To use this initializer, create an array of `Pixel` and then call `NSImage` passing in the `pixels`, `width`, and `height`. It returns an optional `NSImage` which is `nil` if anything went wrong creating the image.

**Example Usage:**

```
let height = 500
let width = 500

var pixels: [Pixel] = .init(repeating: .init(a: 0, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0), count: width * height)
for index in pixels.indices {
    pixels[index].a = 255
    pixels[index].r = .random(in: 0...255)
    pixels[index].g = .random(in: 0...255)
    pixels[index].b = .random(in: 0...255)
}
let image = NSImage(pixels: pixels, width: width, height: height)
```

Thanks to @LeoDabus for suggesting making the function a convenience initializer of `NSImage`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216113/discussion-on-answer-by-vacawama-create-random-pixel-images-in-swift).

Answer (score 3):

You can use below func to create random UIImage

```
    public struct PixelData {
        var a: UInt8
        var r: UInt8
        var g: UInt8
        var b: UInt8
    }

    func createRandomUIImage(width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage? {
        var pixels = [PixelData]()
        let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
        let bitsPerComponent = 8
        let bitsPerPixel = 32

        for _ in 0..<width {
            for _ in 0..<height {
                pixels.append(PixelData(a: .random(in: 0...255), r: .random(in: 0...255), g: .random(in: 0...255), b: .random(in: 0...255)))
            }
        }

        guard let providerRef = CGDataProvider(data: NSData(bytes: &pixels,
                                length: pixels.count * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size)
            )
            else { return nil }

        guard let cgim = CGImage(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent,
            bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel,
            bytesPerRow: width * MemoryLayout<PixelData>.size,
            space: rgbColorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo,
            provider: providerRef,
            decode: nil,
            shouldInterpolate: true,
            intent: .defaultIntent
            )
            else { return nil }

        return UIImage(cgImage: cgim)
    }
```

Comment: 1) OP is going to need an `NSImage` instead of a `UIImage` for use in macOS.  Notice that OP is importing cocoa and creating an `NSViewController`. 2) You are using the code from one of my other answers without credit.

Comment: I think that the point here is to help the OP. I have made modification on the code and check whether it works on XCode. I did not notice that OP imported the Cocoa. OP can accept any answer that works for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super-fast solution that uses Accelerate's BNNS and vImage libraries. You can generate a `UIImage` or an `NSImage` from a `CGImage`.

```
import Accelerate

let cgImage = makeRandomImage(width: 1024,
                              height: 640)!
let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage,
                      size: CGSize(width: cgImage.width,
                                   height: cgImage.height))

func makeRandomImage(width: Int, height: Int) -> CGImage? {

    let imageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 8 * 3,
        colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue))!
    
    let arrayDescriptor = BNNSNDArrayDescriptor.allocate(
        randomIn: Pixel_8(0) ... 255,
        shape: .matrixRowMajor(width * imageFormat.componentCount,
                               height))
    
    let imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: arrayDescriptor.data,
                                    height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                                    width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                                    rowBytes: width)
    
    return try? imageBuffer.createCGImage(format: imageFormat)
}
```